Proxy local TCP connections using nginx
I need to proxy TCP connections from my local PC using nginx.
I want to open a TCP connection (via .NET client) to a specific address and port, let's call it backend.
I cannot directly access it and I can only access it if the TCP connection goes through an internal TCP proxy and port. The proxy configured is able to access the backend.
Let's assume backend's IP = XX.XXX.XXX.XX and we want to connect to its port YYYY.
Proxy configured: proxy.example.com at port 9090 and is already accessible via TCP.
Can I use nginx so that when my PC listens for TCP connections to 127.0.0.1:YYYY
a) forwards them to  proxy.example.com:9090
b) configures header(s) in order for the proxy to forward them to the original backend IP & correct YYYY port?
I tried the following configuration:
stream {

  server {
    listen YYYY;

    proxy_pass proxy.example.com:9090;
    proxy_protocol on;
    set_real_ip_from  XX.XXX.XXX.XX;
  }
}

